# How to check position in array and compare two fields which color they have? [chess]

Tags: ruby

It's my homework. I got confused and I'm looking for help. Could you tell me what I should learn to figure out these kinds of tasks? I got 2 coordinates from chess board and I'd like to input values from array and it tells me whether fields are the same color or not from these two coordinates e.g. a1 and b2 (two black color fields) or a1 and d1 (one black and one white). I realized that I can get indexes from the array and check whether they are even or odd and then we can say which color of field it is?

/ this is what I did

```html
=begin

    a b c d e f g h

8   o x o x o x o x   8
7   x o x o x o x o   7
6   o x o x o x o x   6
5   x o x o x o x o   5
4   o x o x o x o x   4
3   x o x o x o x o   3
2   o x o x o x o x   2
1   x o x o x o x o   1

    a b c d e f g h

x - even <--- color:black, o - odd <--- color:white
=end



array_pos_x = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]
array_pos_y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

module Enumerable
  def even_values
    r = []
    self.each_index {|x| r << self[x] if x%2==0}
    r
  end
end

#        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# index   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  ---> even index from array 1 3 5 7          x%2==0   ==   x.even?
#                                 ---> odds index from array                  x%2==1  ==    x.odd?

p array_pos_x.even_values
p array_pos_y.even_values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to determine if two locations on the board, `[i1,j1]` and `[i2,j2]`, are the same colour. Here the `i`'s are base-zero indices for rows and the `j`'s are base-zero indices for the columns, the "bottom-left" location (row offset `0` and column offset `0`) being black.

You need a method that returns the colour of any given cell, say, `:black` or `:white`, and then write:

```
colour(i1,j1) == colour(i2,j2)
```

which will return `true` or `false`. We can write that method as follows.

```
def colour(i,j)
  i.even? == j.even? ? :black : :white
end
```

For example,

```
(0..2).each do |i|
  (0..2).each { |j| puts "#{i} #{j} #{colour(i,j)}" }
end
0 0 black
0 1 white
0 2 black
1 0 white
1 1 black
1 2 white
2 0 black
2 1 white
2 2 black
```

If you wish to label rows as in the example you could first create the hashes

```
row_labels = {0=>"1", 1=>"2", 2=>"3", 3=>"4", 4=>"5", 5=>"6", 6=>"7", 7=>"8"}
col_labels = {0=>"a", 1=>"b", 2=>"c", 3=>"d", 4=>"e", 5=>"f", 6=>"g", 7=>"h"}
```

and then write (for example) the following.

```
(0..2).each do |i|
  (0..2).each { |j| puts "#{row_labels[i]} #{col_labels[j]} #{colour(i,j)}" }
end
1 a black
1 b white
1 c black
2 a white
2 b black
2 c white
3 a black
3 b white
3 c black
```

---

We can ask a user for the coordinates of two locations and then compare their colours as follows.

```
ROW_LABEL_TO_IDX =
  {"1"=>0, "2"=>1, "3"=>2, "4"=>3, "5"=>4, "6"=>5, "7"=>6, "8"=>7} 
COL_LABEL_TO_IDX = 
  {"a"=>0, "b"=>1, "c"=>2, "d"=>3, "e"=>4, "f"=>5, "g"=>6, "h"=>7}

def request_loc
  [ROW_LABEL_TO_IDX[request_row_or_col('row (1-8)', '1'..'8')],
   COL_LABEL_TO_IDX[request_row_or_col('column (a-h)', 'a'..'h')]]
end

def request_row_or_col(lbl, rng)
  loop do
    print "Please enter a #{lbl}: "
    s = gets.chomp.downcase
    break s if rng.include?(s)
    puts "That entry is invalid"
  end 
end
```

See [Range#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F).

The following is one possible dialogue.

```
i1, j1 = request_loc
Please enter a row (1-8): 0
That entry is invalid
Please enter a row (1-8): 9
That entry is invalid
Please enter a row (1-8): a
That entry is invalid
Please enter a row (1-8): 2
Please enter a column (a-h): 2
That entry is invalid
Please enter a column (a-h): i
That entry is invalid 
Please enter a column (a-h): b
   #=> [1, 1]
i1 #=> 1
j1 #=> 1
```

```
i2, j2 = request_loc
Please enter a row (1-8): 3
Please enter a column (a-h): D
   #=> [2, 3]
i2 #=> 2
j2 #=> 3
```

We may now compare the colours at the two locations.

```
colour(i1,j1) == colour(i2,j2)
  #=> colour(1,1) == colour(2,3)
  #=> :black == :white
  #=> false
```

---

Note that instead of creating the method `colour`, which returns `:black` or `:white`, we could write

```
def black?(i,j)
  i.even? == j.even?
end
```

which returns `true` or `false`, and compare

```
black?(i1,j1) == black?(i2,j2)
```

which returns `true` if both sides are `true` (both are black) or both sides are `false` (both are white).

Comment: What if I want input from terminal two coordinates: i1,j1 and i2,j2 and check whether there are the coordinates on array.and then compare the color.

Comment: bubuq3, I edited my answer to show how that might be done.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you :)